# Jquery validation based on expando attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I am trying to validate an input based on attributes (data-inStock) that this input has:

HTML:

```html
<input type="number" name="stockQuantity" class="stockQuantity" data-inStock="5" />
```

```html
jQuery.validator.addClassRules("stockQuantity", {
            required: true,
            min: 0,
            max: **value in data-inStock attribute,**
        });
```

So in this case how can i read the value "data-inStock" from inside the jquery validator?

Answer (score 0):

You get your max using:

```
parseInt(
  jQuery('[name="stockQuantity"]')
  .data('inStock')
);
```

Comment: can i refer to the data-inStock attribute with something like **$(this)**.data("inStock") because i don't know the name of the input. it is being created dynamically

Comment: It's an option object, therefore the `this` pointer doesn't point to what you think it points to. The best you can do is using the class instead of the attribute (`jQuery(".stockQuantity")`)